# ¿ Cómo se llama este tipo de menú deslizable?

Tags: android

Me gustaría poder implementar este tipo de deslizable en mi Android pero no puedo buscar información al respecto pues no sé como se llama. He intentado buscarlo por Google de múltiples formas pero no hay manera, ¿Alguien lo sabe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En Android está el `NumberPicker` el cual puedes crear un XML para customizarlo :) puedes leer antes que todo https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Answer (score 1):

Siento decirte que ese desplegable es de `Swift` y no de `Android` aunque no sé si habrá alguna forma de personalizarlo para que tenga ese estilo. Sin embargo, no de manera nativa.

En `Swift`, los puedes crear usando [`UIPickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview).

En `Android`, puedes crear los desplegables mediante [`Spinner`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

Comment: La respuesta que buscaba es la de x4mp73r pero la tuya también me sirve, y te doy como respuesta válida al menos, gracias!